# Change the initial applications in the Mock RPM build environment

Tags: mocking, java, rpm

Underneath the /var/lib/mock folder of my CentOS 6.2 machine, I can see all the initial applications in a target build OS. If I want to add JDK as an extra application, how can I do it please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the buildrequires in your spec files. Minimal buildroot rarely needs to be touched.

If you really, **really** need to modify minimal buildroot, you will have to create additional (empty) repository with `createrepo` and use something like this for comps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE comps PUBLIC "-//Red Hat, Inc.//DTD Comps info//EN" "comps.dtd">
<comps>
  <group>
    <id>buildsys-build</id>
    <_name>Buildsystem building group</_name>
    <_description/>
    <default>false</default>
    <uservisible>false</uservisible>
    <packagelist>
      <packagereq type="mandatory">openjdk-1.7.0-java</packagereq>
    </packagelist>
  </group>
</comps>
```

Then add this repository to mock config file you are using and add one following line in main section of yum config:

```
   ...
   config_opts['yum.conf'] = """
   [main]
   overwrite_groups = 0
   ...
   """
```

`overwrite_groups = 0` means that yum will merge original buildsys-build group with your new group therefore adding JDK into minimal buildroot (provided `chroot_setup_cmd` is `groupinstall buildsys-build`)